# Creating and naming objects procedurally during runtime

Tags: c#

I've been looking for ways to create multiple instances of a class cPerson during runtime.

I'm using a List to hold all of the cPerson objects but I need to be able to add more to the list within a method. The only relevant questions I've found have involved using a dictionary as a solution but I'm wondering if that's 100% necessary.

tl;dr

Is there any way in C# to name an object at runtime?

```
void Method()
{
    People.Add(new cPerson "unique generated name")
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Name of what?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Name an object".

Comment: If you really care about instance name, or you want map to `Person` object to a `name` consider using a `Dictionary<string,Person>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but if you want a unique name you could just use the count of items in the list for a name (Assuming you want to pass the name in the Initialize args).

```
void Method()
{
    People.Add(new cPerson(People.Count));
}
```

You could also create an array of names and use that:

```
string[] names = { "Brad", "Ben", "Mark", "James", "Steve", "Laura", "Jon" };
void Method()
{
    People.Add(new cPerson(names[names.Length - 1]);
}
```

Or you could even create a `random` to create a random name and an array of names:

```
string[] names = { "Brad", "Ben", "Mark", "James", "Steve", "Laura", "Jon" };
Random rand = new Random();
void Method()
{
    People.Add(new cPerson(names[rand.Next(names.Length)]);
}
```